# slice, action and reducers, what are they?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to learn Redux, and i encountered this code:

```
reducers: {
    loginStart: (state) => {
      //...
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      //...
    },
    loginFailure: (state) => {
      //...
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      //...
    },
  },
});
export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

I can't understand well what are `.actions`, `Slice`, `.reducer` or `reducers` from different web sources.
So kindly can any expert in Redux here explain in a simplified way what are theses and their roles?

Comment: The best answer here would be to go through our official Redux docs tutorials, which will teach you all of these concepts: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: i did seen the official tutorial, but i can't totally understand all of it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every state of your app (which is global) lives in an object tree stored in a single store.

Actions are simply JavaScript objects that have a type with a payload of data illustrating exactly what is happening. what they do? they are the only way to manage our state tree. pay attention: no state has been mutated so far.

Reducers are just responses to our corresponding called action to perform on our immutable state and thus returning a new state. optionally you might also want to check [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to better understand reducers.

What is slice then? as it comes with [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), slice contains all the reducer logics and actions for a single feature.
it auto generates your action creators and types which you have to define them as constants before redux-toolkit. check [createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) for the full explanation.

In your example the object called reducers goes into your createSlice with also an initial state and a name.

Based on all that being said, this is your final example of your question:

```
const initialState = {}
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authentication',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
          //...
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
          //...
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
          //...
        },
        logout: (state) => {
          //...
        },
    },
})
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions
export default counterSlice.reducer
```